# Cross-browser localStorage

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, local-storage, opera

i imagined a todo list written in plain JS without using framework just to see the localStorage cross-browser compatibility.

The script is

```
function addText(){
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
date = new Date();
var time = date.getTime();
if (input !== "") {
    localStorage.setItem(time,"lalala");
    document.getElementById('input').value = '';
}};

function loadText(){
if (window.localStorage) {
        for(var i in window.localStorage){
            console.log(i+"--------theiiiiiii");
            var z = localStorage.getItem(i);
            console.log(z+"--------you keep me satisfied");
    }
} else {
    alert("Your Browser does not support LocalStorage.");
}
}
```

Now, i Chrome works, in Firefox almost, in opera i get set values plus all the localStorage operators. Does anybody know a solution to this?

```
1381311087810--------theiiiiiii
lalala--------you keep me satisfied
length--------theiiiiiii
null--------you keep me satisfied
key--------theiiiiiii
null--------you keep me satisfied
getItem--------theiiiiiii
null--------you keep me satisfied
setItem--------theiiiiiii
null--------you keep me satisfied
removeItem--------theiiiiiii
null--------you keep me satisfied
clear--------theiiiiiii
null--------you keep me satisfied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by listing only the keys:

```
function loadText(){
    if (window.localStorage) {

        /// list all keys from object
        var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);

        for(var i, key; key = keys[i]; i++) {
            console.log(key + "--------theiiiiiii");
            var z = localStorage.getItem(key);
            console.log(z + "--------you keep me satisfied");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Your Browser does not support LocalStorage.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime i managed to have it working in Opera. In my case it was all about the key and the value as a multilevel JSON. This way i can ignore any kind of browser fault on interpreting localStorage.

Comment: How did you do it @DeckPope? Thanks!