# How to create data-id dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before asking my help I would like to explain how my app works. I am creating a group of some users. To create a group, select some check boxes and hit group button, give some name and hit ok. This group name will appear on the table right side. Now to check the group members, click the group name and the respective check boxes will be selected. Example in this fiddle, when you click on the test2 group name then on the left side last 3 rows check boxes will be selected. This is working fine.

**My problem** In the users tab, when there is a form which accepts name, mobile and phone number. After filling all the fields and when the add button is pressed then a new gets added on the left side. Now suppose If I want to create a group be selecting the check box of this newly created row then it does not show me any data-id and yes it should know because in this `<td><input data-id="46" type="checkbox"></td>` the number 46 is the auto increment number from the mysql table.So when a row gets inserted this id gets increased. This happens in back end. Please tell me how to do this in front end. This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/265/) and this is [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/265/embedded/result/) of the fiddle(because the tabs are not working in small screen and I do not know why).

Comment: The problem is that you're storing your entire application state in the DOM. The DOM can be used to *display* data, but you should not use it store it.

Comment: @Blender how do you come to know that I am stroing entire data in DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the last data-id into a global variable like,

```
var current_user_count;

function addUser(){
   current_user_count = parseInt($('td').last().attr('data-id')):
   current_user_count +=1;
   $("element").append('<td data-id="current_user_count"></td>')
}
```

Add this function **addUser()** for the button click.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,which button click do i need to add this?

Comment: you are adding a user rite ? So add this for "Add user" button

Comment: I did your way but I am getting error in the console *Unexpected token ;*  and this is pointing to this line * current_user_count +=1;*

Comment: current_user_count = current_user_count + 1 ;

Comment: This time its showing a different error *Unexpected token +* pointing to this line *current_user_count = current_user_count + 1 ;*

Comment: Did you console the value of current_user_count ? .. P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43906/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-tony-jose)

Comment: you went off the chat?

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage or sessionstorage based on how the variable should reset. You can also use cookie.

Here is the **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wNX9/)**

```
if(!localStorage.count) {
    localStorage.count = 0;   
}
localStorage.count++;
var num = localStorage.count;
$("#shortfall").text(num);
```

Comment: Yes, you can use local storage also, a better option.

Comment: In which function do I need to add this?

Comment: The moment user presses add button

Comment: @TonyJose, `localStorage` is not cross browser. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268459/cross-browser-localstorage

Comment: Yeah.. but it has its own advantages in html5 supported browsers.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar you wrote *$("#shortfall").text(num);* so which Id should I write?

Comment: @JqueryLearner:Than is just for displaying in fiddle you need to use localstorage for getting and setting.

Comment: I am writng your code after this line $('#btn1').click(function () { but getting error

Comment: @MilindAnantwar 2 errors I am getting 1st one is * Unexpected identifier* and its pointing to *localStorage.count = 0;* and 2nd error is *Unexpected token ;* and its poiting to *var num = localStorage.count;*

Comment: it would be great if you can create fiddle

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I have already posted the fiddle in my questions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43915/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-milind-anantwar)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I was waiting for your answer